# Correlated subquery in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, correlated-subquery

I have a employee table and `EmployeeCourseStatus` table.

I want to display the list of each employee with a count of courses completed(`status = "CMP"`).

I have following correlated subquery which results in error below:

```
var query = (from emp in Employee
                     join adr in EmployeeAddress on emp.id = adr.EmployeeID
                     select new
                     {
                        id = emp.id,
                        name=emp.name,
                        country=adr.country,
                        CompletedCourseCount = (from c in employeeCourseStatus where c.empid = emp.id && c.status == "CMP" select c.id).count()
                     }
```

Error:

> Only Premitive types are supported.

The equivalent SQL subquery would be -

```
Select emp.id
       , emp.name
       , adr.Country
       , CompletedCourseCount = (select count(id) from EmployeeCourseStatus where id = emp.id and status = "CMP") 
from   Employee emp
       JOIN employeeaddress adr ON adr.EmployeeID = emp.ID
```

Comment: Linq to Objects for EF Ver 4.2

Comment: LINQ to objects has nothing to do with EF. What do you mean?

Comment: My bad - using LINQ to Entities

Answer (score 3):

Use `equals` keyword when joining sequences

```
var query = from emp in Employee
            join adr in EmployeeAddress on emp.id equals adr.EmployeeID
            join c in EmployeeCourseStatus on emp.id equals c.empid into courses
            select new
            {
               id = emp.id,
               name = emp.name,
               country = adr.country,
               CompletedCourseCount = courses.Where(x => x.status == "CMP").Count()
            };
```

Comment: Why do you use the Join method twice (EmployeeAddress and EmployeeCourseStatus)?

Comment: @mveith to avoid nested `from` query

Comment: The 'into courses' at the end of the second join,in the subquery, was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i know this is old thread but like to know why you use join in linq query where it is solved in sql without join.

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing `where c.empid = emp.id` with `where c.empid == emp.id` in your count query.

If that does not work, what are the types of `emp.name` and `adr.country`?

Comment: both emp.name and adr.country are string. The error is - Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using lambda expressions (for readability - especially in Join method):

```
Employee.Join(EmployeeAddress, emp => emp.id, adr => adr.EmployeeID, (emp, adr) => new
{
    id = emp.id,
    name = emp.name,
    country = adr.country,
    CompletedCourseCount = employeeCourseStatus.Count(c => c.empid == emp.id && c.status == "CMP")
});
```

Comment: Not everyone would agree that this is an increase in readability :-)

Comment: This is a matter of taste, I actually prefer the opposite - lambdas in all cases except a join clause :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Honestly, why anybody thinks ANY lambda expression beyond very simple ones is more readable is beyond me. It's especially bad when people start chaining and nesting them, which the whole paradigm seems to lend itself to, and then in their feverish bid to get as much code as possible on one line they start nest ternary operators inside of nested and chained lambdas. It quickly goes from "Oh, that's handy" to "Geez, that's a completely unreadable mess". It's like Regular Expressions, perfect where they fit, but just because you CAN doesn't mean you SHOULD.